# Xslt to translate one to another and adding a row

Tags: xslt, xsd

Say I have an XML like this. I want to introduce a `<row3>` element.

```
<create xmlns="urn:partner.com"
  <objects xmlns:p0="urn:s.partner.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="p0:IED">
    <row1 xmlns="urn:s.partner.com">BookingDataFromCastIron</row1>
    <row2 xmlns="urn:s.partner.com">Csv</row2>
  </objects>
</create>"
```

I am using the following XSLT. But it is giving the same XML as output. Am I missing anything?

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="objects">  
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:element name="type">IED</xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is all to do with the namespaces, basically your template match above only hits `object` if there is no namespace in the source XML. However you do have a namespace set `xmlns="urn:partner.com"` so you need to use the following to remove the binding to the namespace: `<xsl:template match="*:objects">`.

I think you are looking for this, but it defiantly pushes you in the right direction:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*:objects">  
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <xsl:element name="row3" xmlns="urn:s.partner.com">IED</xsl:element>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<create xmlns="urn:partner.com">
   <objects xmlns:p0="urn:s.partner.com"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <row1 xmlns="urn:s.partner.com">BookingDataFromCastIron</row1>
      <row2 xmlns="urn:s.partner.com">Csv</row2>
      <row3 xmlns="urn:s.partner.com">IED</row3>
   </objects>
</create>
```